# python OR-tools printing a solution when the solution is a list of numbers

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I want to print the solution in OR-tools when the solution is a 2D array of pairs with a different number of pairs each time.

For example i have this code

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
numberOfPairs = 4

listOfPairs = [[model.NewIntVar(0, 5, 'x_{i}'.format(i=i+2*j)) for i in range(2)] for j in range(numberOfPairs)]

status = solver.Solve(model)
if status in [cp_model.OPTIMAL, cp_model.FEASIBLE]:
    ###############################
else:
    print('unsat')
```

what do i need to replace the ######'s with to print out the solution x_0 = 4, x_1 = 3, x_2 = 2 .........etc

Answer (score 0):

it looks like all you're doing is creating some variables that can potentially span from 0 to 5. You're never setting any constraints on those variables, thus the variables after solving will always be false. Here's some code to show a variable is never true in your example:

```
if status in [cp_model.OPTIMAL, cp_model.FEASIBLE]:
    for l in listOfPairs:
        for v in l:
            if solver.Value(v):
                print(v)
```